# Python HTTP POST Osmand live track

Tags: python, http, traccar

I am trying to send HTTP POST to traccar from a python application.
How can i use requests to send it in the following format (osmand):

[http://demo.traccar.org:5055/?id=123456&lat={0}&lon={1}&timestamp={2}&hdop={3}&altitude={4}&speed={5}](http://demo.traccar.org:5055/?id=123456&lat=%7B0%7D&lon=%7B1%7D&timestamp=%7B2%7D&hdop=%7B3%7D&altitude=%7B4%7D&speed=%7B5%7D)

Requests post syntax= requests.post(url, params={key: value}, args)

It works great when i use cURL.

Any one having any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For POST you should use body instead of query parameters. You should be able to send it with something like this

```
requests.post('http://demo.traccar.org:5055', data = {'lat': y, 'lon': x})
```